# How autofill is disabled here and how to restore it?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

There's a website where password autofill doesn't work (it works for the username, but then not for the password), I suppose because it is disabled by web developers, but I want to add it back via Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey.

But the `<form>` element has no `autocomplete="off"` attribute, and there's no `<input>` element with similar `autocomplete="off"` attribute, so I can't even find a way to change the HTML via the web inspector to make password autofill work.

What are other techniques to disable password autofill?

I checked in my Safari preferences and I have not disabled autofill for that particular website.

If you want the actual sample, here it is:

https://ac.windtre.it/oa/auth/login (click the "ENTRA" button, then `document.forms[1]`'s elements becomes visible)

Here's an extract of the HTML from the same page, for archiving purposes:

```
<form _ngcontent-hyb-c164="" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" style="">
  <mat-form-field _ngcontent-hyb-c164="" class="mat-form-field full-width ng-tns-c57-2 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted mat-form-field-invalid ng-touched mat-form-field-hide-placeholder">
    <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c57-2">
      <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c57-2">
        <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c57-2">

          <input
            type="password"
            id="mat-input-1"
            class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c57-2 ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-touched"
            matinput=""
            formcontrolname="password"
            aria-invalid="true"
            aria-required="false"
            _ngcontent-hyb-c164=""
          >
          <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c57-2">
            <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c57-2 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-3" for="mat-input-1" aria-owns="mat-input-1">
              <mat-label _ngcontent-hyb-c164="" class="ng-tns-c57-2 ng-star-inserted">Inserisci password</mat-label>
            </label>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-form-field-suffix ng-tns-c57-2 ng-star-inserted">
          <mat-icon _ngcontent-hyb-c164="" role="img" matsuffix="" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-tns-c57-2" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font">visibility_off </mat-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c57-2 ng-star-inserted">
        <span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c57-2"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c57-2">
        <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c57-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c57-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding tags to the inputs such as `name="username"`

Browser autofills rely on the input names to prefill and autocomplete them. That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the browser with `type` attribute. There is also a `autocomplete` attribute to change the behaviour.

```html
<input type='password' autocomplete='password' />
```